# Can I apply for a Schengen visa if my US residency expires in less than 90 days after my return?

Tags: visas, usa, schengen, europe, h1b-visas

I am planning a winter vacation in Iceland around the dates of Dec 21st, 2017 to Jan 1st, 2018. I am currently on H1B visa in the USA, and my visa expires on Feb 7, 2018. My employer has applied for the H1B visa extension.

Although my visa is valid until Feb 2018, it does not satisfy the 90-day validity after the departure from Schengen countries. In that case, can I show the H1B extension receipt as a proof of document?

Answer (score 4):

Since I do not have enough reputation to comment, I am writing my experience as an answer.

I think it depends on the immigration officer. I was in a similar situation when I visited France in June 2017. The French consulate granted me the visa but the immigration officer noticed that my USA visa (J1 visa) would be expiring in two months from the date of my entry in France. So the officer asked me my return flight ticket which I showed him, and I was allowed to enter France.